# RabbitMQ using Direct Exchange when Topic was specified

Tags: java, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

In my application I have 3 classes:
- Company, which hires Workers for any of 3 jobs
- Workers, each can do 2 jobs
- Administrator, which receives copies of all messages in the program and can send messages to all companies, all workers or just everyone

I'm using `work.companies.companyName` for companies keys and `work.workers.workerName` for workers keys, they both use default exchange and queue for communication. The Administrator receives messages with `admin` Topic Exchange.

The problem is with the Administrator -> everyone else communication. It works exactly like Direct exchange - I can get Companies and Workers any names, even like "#", "company1.#" etc. and they won't receive anything, unless in the Administrator I explicitly send the message with key like "work.companies.company1".
I would like to be able to use just e. g. "work.companies.#" to send message to all companies. What am I doing wrong?

Administrator.java:

```
public class Administrator
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TimeoutException
    {
        new Thread(new TopicListener("admin", ign -> {})).start();
        TopicWriter writer = new TopicWriter();
    // lots of code
```

TopicListener.java:

```
public class TopicListener implements Runnable
{
    private final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "space";
    private String key;
    private Consumer<String> msgHandler;

    public TopicListener(String key, Consumer<String> msgHandler)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.msgHandler = msgHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.setHost("localhost");
            Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
            Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

            channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "topic");

            String queueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
            channel.queueBind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, key);

            com.rabbitmq.client.Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel)
            {
                @Override
                public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
                {
                    String msg = new String(body, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    System.out.println("Received: \"" + msg + "\"");
                    msgHandler.accept(msg);
                }
            };

            channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);
        }
        catch (IOException | TimeoutException e)
        { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

TopicWriter.java:

```
public class TopicWriter
{
    private final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "space";
    private final Channel channel;

    public TopicWriter() throws IOException, TimeoutException
    {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        this.channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "topic");
    }

    public void send(String msg, String key) throws IOException
    {
        channel.basicPublish(
                EXCHANGE_NAME,
                key,
                null,
                msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

Company.java contains:

```
new Thread(new TopicListener("space.agencies." + agencyID, ign -> {})).start();
```

Worker.java contains:

```
new Thread(new TopicListener("space.carriers." + carrierID, consumer)).start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out where the problem was: I was trying to **send** message to everyone using Topic, where in RabbitMQ Topic is used to specify who should **receive** the message. The "#" or "*" should be used in the queue key declaration, not while sending the message with a given key.